# Scaling Puppet - when is too much for WEBrick?

Tags: scalability, puppet, webrick

I've found the following at [Docs: Scaling Puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/scaling.html):

> Are you using the default webserver?
>
> WEBrick, the default web server used to enable Puppet’s web services connectivity, is essentially a reference implementation, and becomes unreliable beyond about ten managed nodes. In any sort of production environment serving many nodes, you should switch to a more efficient web server implementation such as Passenger or Mongrel.

Where does the the number 10 come from in "ten managed nodes"?

I have a little over 20 nodes and I might soon have little over 30.  Should I change to Passenger or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should change to Passenger when you start having problems with WEBrick (or a little before).  When that happens for you will depend on your workload.

The biggest problem with WEBrick is that it's single-threaded and blocking; once it's started working on a request, it cannot handle any other requests until it's done with the first one.  Thus, what will make the difference to you is how much of the time Puppet spends processing requests.

Each time a client asks for its catalog, that's a request.  Each separate file retrieved via `puppet:///` URLs is also a request.  If you're using Puppet lightly, each catalog won't take too long to generate, you won't be distributing many files on any given Puppet run, and each client won't be taking more than four to six seconds of server time every hour.  If each client takes four seconds of server time per hour, 10 clients have a 5% chance of collisions<sup>0</sup>--of at least one client having to wait while another's request is processed.  For 20 or 30 clients, those chances are 19% and 39%, respectively.  As long as each request is short, you might be able to live with some contention, but the odds of collisions increase pretty quickly, so if you've got more than, say, 50 hosts (75% collision chance) you really ought to by using Passenger unless you're doing active performance measuring that shows that you're doing okay.

If, however, you're working your Puppet master harder--taking longer to generate catalogs, serving lots of files, serving large files, or whatever--you need to switch to Passenger sooner.  I inherited a set of about thirty hosts with a WEBrick Puppet master where things were doing okay, but when I started deploying new systems, all of the Puppet traffic caused by a fresh deployment (including a couple of gigabyte files<sup>1</sup>) was preventing other hosts from getting their updates, so that's when I was forced to switch to Passenger.

In short, you'll probably be okay with 30 nodes if you're not doing anything too intense with Puppet, but at that point you *need* to be monitoring the performance of at least your Puppet master and preferably your clients' update status, too, so you'll know when you start running beyond the capabilities of WEBrick.

<sup>0</sup> This is a standard [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox) calculation; if *n* is the number of clients and *s* is the average number of seconds of server time each client uses per hour, then the chance of having at least one collision during an hour is given by `1-(s/3600)!/((s/3600)^n*((s/3600)-n)!)`.

<sup>1</sup> Puppet isn't really a good avenue for distributing files of this size in any case.  I eventually switched to putting them on an NFS share that all of the hosts had access to.

Answer (score 2):

For 20-30 nodes, there shouldn't be any problem. Note that `passenger` provides some additional features. It may be faster serving the nodes, but I am not sure how much improvement you will get if you have only 30 nodes.

You should change to `passenger` if you are using more than hundred nodes. I started seeing problems when the number of nodes requesting service from the puppet-master reached about 200.  In my case, with the default web-server, about 5% of the nodes (random) couldn't receive the catalog during hourly run.